# mysql create view only if it doesn't already exist

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-view

How do I create a view only if it doesn't exist. If it does exist, I want to drop the view and redefine it. I also want no warnings or errors.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ...
```

[Details here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-view.html) ;-)

Comment: darn, you beat me to it and i didn't get a notification an answer was posted already. so +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW <view name>
AS
<your select expression goes here>
```